# MSMQ Message from C# to C++ body is parsed with each letter being separated by '0

Tags: c#, c++, msmq

I'm sending a message to an MSMQ from C# (ActiveXFormatter) and trying to read it in C++. 
The body that I read is indeed the body of the message I sent but there is a '0' between each two characters (in C++).
I think it has to do with encoding but I'm not sure how to fix it.
I'm opening the MSMQ with `VT_VECTOR | VT_UI1`.

I've try opening the MSMQ with `VT_BSTR` with no luck

In C# I'm sending the message with a simple ActiveXFormatter
`_sendQueue.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
_sendQueue.Send(myString);`

Comment: `ActiveXMessageFormatter` - what do you use on the C++ side?

Comment: `0` between each character is typical for UTF-16 (MS-Windows default Unicode) when sending only ASCII (as Unicode). So sending "ABCD" is received as "A\0B\0C\0D\0".  Treat the characters received on the C++ side as wide chars UTF-16LE encoded.

Comment: How would I do that in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the Encoding in C# and sending a null-terminated byte array.